# Sending a skype message by ip or mac addresses

Tags: network, mac-address, skype, ip

If I know someone's ip, mac addresses and a computer name in a local wifi network, and also that there is skype running on their computer (and port), can send them a message through skype? Can I find out their skype user name?

Answer (score 1):

Skype traffic travels through the Skype central servers. You cannot directly connect.

Comment: I don't want to connect to it.

Comment: Then the answer is simple: you cannot find out a Skype username based on IP/mac/computername